# SqlDataReader.Read and large records

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, sqldatareader

I get some weird behaviour when using SqlDataReader.Read() when the result set contains a large column.

What happens is:

- The entire record is not read
- The record remains locked after reader and connection is closed.

unless I explicitly call `reader.Get*` on the large column.

Here is some test code to show what I mean.

```
CREATE TABLE TestXml (
    Id int NOT NULL
   ,number int NOT NULL
   ,data xml NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TestXml
VALUES (1, 0, (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML PATH('Objects')))
      ,(2, 0, (SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM sys.objects FOR XML PATH('Objects')))
      ,(3, 0, (SELECT TOP 10000 a.* FROM sys.objects a, sys.objects b FOR XML PATH('Objects')))
```

The code to fetch data

```
const int TestId = 1;

using (var connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var connection2 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var command1 = new SqlCommand())
using (var command2 = new SqlCommand()) {
    command1.Connection = connection1;
    command1.CommandText =
        "SELECT Id, number, data " +
        "FROM TestXml " +
        "WHERE Id = @Id";

    command2.Connection = connection2;
    command2.CommandText = 
        "UPDATE TestXml " + 
        "SET number = number + 1 " +
        "WHERE Id = @Id";

    connection1.Open();
    connection2.Open();

    command1.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TestId;
    using (var reader = command1.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.Read()) {
            var id = reader.GetInt32(0);

            //// reader.GetValue(2);
            command2.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

When Id = 1 or 2  => update works fine.
When Id = 3 => timeout exception.

If I uncomment `reader.GetValue(2)`, Id = 3 works fine as well.

Is this expected behaviour of the reader?
Shouldn't closing the reader cancel the query and release locks?

I know I can use `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` to stream the result but in this case the large object was not planned.

**Edit**: Just to show that you don't need an update to have the lock remain after reader is closed. Any exception will close the reader but keep the lock on the record, e.g.

```
using (var connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var command1 = new SqlCommand())
    command1.Connection = connection1;
    command1.CommandText =
        "SELECT Id, number, data " +
        "FROM TestXml " +
        "WHERE Id = 3";

    connection1.Open();

    using (var reader = command1.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.Read()) {
            var id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            throw new Exception("whatever");
        }
    }
}
```

(Row 3 is still locked)

Comment: Two recommendations 1) See the command timeout to a larger number.  The default is 5 minutes which may not be long enough to complete the query. 2) Put query into a BackGroundWorker so the application doesn't get locked out.  When I have a large SQL query in a Form application the form get hung so putting the query into a BackGroundWorker allows the form to still operate while the query is running.

Comment: I think you might be running into locking issues with the way you're accessing the same table in different connections etc; which is what causes your other issues. It's difficult to say, because the approach seems strange; to run a select from a table to update it again in another when it can be done in a single query - but there might be more behind the scenes than this?

Comment: @jdweng. this is just an example to show that reader.Read might not read the entire record and that locks might not be cleared when the reader is closed. My code is very different but suffers from the same problem.

Comment: For very large databases I've been using sqlcmd.exe and saving results into a csv file.  I have code that runs sqlcmd.exe from c# using a backgroundworker.  Then I read csv into c# to finish the processing.

Comment: @jdweng, my database is rather small. By accident a large xml was inserted into a table and that caused all kinds of trouble. I have looked around but have not found any warnings on using SqlDataReader on a table which might contain a large value. Is everybody switching to SequentialAccess as soon as there is a varchar(max), varbinary(max) or xml column in the result set? Otherwise it seems like an opening for a possible DOS-attack.

Comment: SQLCmd.exe comes with SQLServer and uses credentials just like c#.  See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162816.aspx

Comment: In your first sample, the first command isn't actually finished before you call the second command, so the lock is not unexpected. In your second sample, it really should be the case that, after the `using` finishes, all server-side resources have been released -- but actually completing the `using` may take arbitrarily long. If the row remains locked after that because the command isn't actually finished yet, I'd call that a bug in the framework. It should certainly disappear if an explicit transaction is used.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, SqlServer uses row level locking (unless escalated) so once the read has passed a row it should not be locked. But I agree it is a race condition but it always works with a smaller row. The second case has nothing to do with the duration of Dispose. The lock stays "forever" (maybe it is cleared when the connection is closed but that might never happen due to pooling). SqlDataReader.Dispose() just closes the client end of the command while the SqlServer end sits there with more data to send.  Wrapping the select command in a transaction makes no difference.

Comment: The issue here is "once a read has passed". If, in order to "pass", a large blob is read in the background because the entire row has to be finished by the ADO.NET code, this could take however long. But however long it takes, it ought to wait for that to complete, or issue a cancellation to SQL Server and wait for *that* to complete. This is completely orthogonal to connection pooling -- disposing resources must dispose. It's not OK for `.Dispose` to simply say "yeah, whatever" and wait for the server to handle things!

Comment: If wrapping it in a transaction really doesn't matter that's quite disappointing, as I'd hoped that code would wait for the rollback to be confirmed by the server.

Comment: @Jeroen, I agree with you but unfortunatly that is not how it works. It is not officially stated in the documentation that `.Read()` reads the entire record but it is sort of implied in the documentation for `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` "Rather than loading the entire row, SequentialAccess enables the DataReader to load data as a stream". I'd consider it a bug in the SqlDataReader but it is probable "by design".